# is there a better, more lightweight way to access session data in codeigniter view?

Tags: codeigniter, notation

Is there a more lightweight way to access session data in a view with codeigniter than posted [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/507906/)?

i think about soemthing like `{session.myparameter}`.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your session data to an array in your controller that pass it to the view with the rest of the page data.

```
$page_data['session_data']  = array(
    'session_param_1' => $this->session->userdata('session_param_1'),
    'session_param_2' => $this->session->userdata('session_param_4'),
    'session_param_3' => $this->session->userdata('session_param_3'),
    'session_param_4' => $this->session->userdata('session_param_2')
);

$this->load->view('your_view', $page_data);
```

To access the session class directly from a view you must ensure that the session library has been loaded by the calling controller, or has been autoloaded in **application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Then access in your view as required.

```
<h2>Logged in as <?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_user_name'); ?> </h2>
```

Comment: so, direct access is not possible?

Comment: Yes it is as long as you have either loaded the session class in your controller or you have added it to your autoload.php list

Comment: would you suggest better to handle it in the controller, and write the needed parameters to the page-data variable, for clean coding?

Comment: I usually access it directly from the view; i think its just a matter of preference